# Does a Socket InputStream read() unblock if server times out?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server that times out after 45 seconds if it hasn't received a full request and closes the connection. I connect to this server through a `Socket` and write my request to the socket's `OutputStream`.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("myhost", myPort);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(properRequestMessage);
out.flush();
```

I'm assuming here that my request is good (follows my protocol). The server is supposed to respond with a file. I try to read from the socket inputstream:

```
BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String in;

while((in = response.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

The `readLine()` blocks here and I think it is because my server thinks my request isn't properly terminated and is therefore waiting for more.

Now, if 45 seconds pass and my server times out, will the `readLine()` unblock or wait for some `Socket` default timeout time?

Comment: how did you configure the timeout on the server and what does it do upon timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on what the server does when it times out.  If it closes the connection you will see that.  If it just logs a message, you might not see anything.

There is no default read timeout. Your readLine() can wait forever.

Comment: My server closes the connection. What do you mean I will see that? The `readLine()` will unblock with `in == null` and break out of the loop?

Comment: That is what the documentation says happens when the end of stream is reached. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the server ***closes*** its end of the socket on that timeout, then [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The `readLine()` method will block until it receives an input or until the underlying socket `read()` timeout ends.
You don't set the timeout on the read command but rather on the socket it self.

[Socket.setSoTimeout(int ms)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

What actually occurs also depends on what the server does, if it closes the socket correctly a `IOException` should be thrown by `readLine()`. If the connection isn't close it will wait for the socket to timeout.