# Thread which gets Information from the server is blocked

Tags: java, multithreading

I have developed a client that sends a request to a client. When the request will be send, then a thread will be launched by the client that hears from the server. For Purpose of Simulation I blocked the response of the server, so the thread will runs und try to hear from the server. But My Thread does not react. Here is some code:

```
void getResponse(){
    System.out.println("###always hearing###");
    BufferedReader bStreamReader=null;
    
    try {
        bStreamReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String responseLine=null;
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        while((responseLine=bStreamReader.readLine())!=null){
            
            getResponse_status=true;
            System.out.println("getResponse_status: "+getResponse_status);
            System.out.println(responseLine);
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("client:reading from server finished");
        bStreamReader.close();
        System.out.println("###finish hearing###");
        //System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
@Override
public void run() { 
    //run method of thread
    getResponse();
}
```

//

The getResponse()-method will be blocked in the while-loop. Normally if the Server does not send anything, then the variable responseLine will be equal null. It means that while-loop will not be executed, since the condition for the execution is not true. But getResponse() will be blocked in the while-loop.  I sure that the server sends nothing. So why is my program blocked in while-loop?

Comment: where do you start the threads?

Comment: If the server doesn't send anything  the first `readLine()` block waiting to receive `end-of-input` character. So I would say it's right it blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readline block until it receives some data. When it receives `end-of-input`character it returns `null`and breaks out of the cycle. As you send nothing it keeps waiting. This is correct.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

> The readLine method waits until the server echoes the information back
>   to EchoClient. When readline returns, EchoClient prints the
>   information to the standard output.
>
> The while loop continues until the user types an end-of-input
>   character.

Your case is pretty much the same. Send something back fro mthe server and see if it makes difference. I believe it does.

**EDIT:**

My suggestion is for the client. In your code do something like:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(5000); // Set read timeout to 5 seconds
```

Before calling this line:

```
bStreamReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

After doing this you will get `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` exception which breaks the cycle if server doesn't respond within 5 seconds. If you enclose it in `try-catch` you are done.

Comment: This is true.  I send something and it worked. I using this method in a thread. So If thread does not hear from the server, then this thread should send a new request. But what should I do if the respond()-method is blocked. My Thread cannot execute the instruction ater respond()-method

Comment: I am simulating the case that server shutdowns

Comment: You want probably set an timeout for read operation. This is done on the socket not on the stream. Default timeout is `0` meaning no-timeout, wait forever. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957019/does-a-socket-inputstream-read-unblock-if-server-times-out. And Tom Cammann's answer to this question.

Comment: it does not help me a lot. I need someting from client-side. I need to unblock the loop from the side of client, so that I can execute the instructions comming after getReponse(); I think, I must wrap it into a thread and kill the thread after a period of time